# If I declare the 'val' variable inside the loop then the code is not showing the desired output but when i put it outside loop it works fine. Reason?

Tags: c++, loops, char

In the below code, If I declare the variable `val` inside the loop then the code is not showing the desired output but when I put it outside the loop it works fine.

What can be the Reason?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    int n ;
    cin>>n ;
    int row=1;
    char val = 'A';
    
    while(row<= n){
        int col=1;
        
        while(col<=n){
            cout<< val ;
            val = val+1;
            col=col+1;

        }
        cout<<endl;
        row=row+1 ;

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger?

Comment: If you declare something inside the loop, you get a new fresh copy each time. Previous updates go away.

Comment: What iy your input? What output do you get for each case and what output do you expect? What loop are you talinkg about? Don't describe your code but show it.

Comment: Add `cout << col << '\n';` before and after the inner loop in both cases and look. Then read about variable scope in your favourite C++ book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variable gets recreated in every iteration for while loop.
The `scope` of the variable is `local` inside the loop so whenever another iteration starts it creates a new copy.

In your case, if you put variable `val` inside the loop, it will be getting recreated with `A` as its value every time. But in `global` scope it only gets initialized once thus fulfilling your purpose.

You can refer to this [Scope of variables](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-of-variables-in-c/) for a better understanding.